# datatables responsive expand/collapse icon disappear

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatables v1.10.11, jquery 1.12.0 and bootstrap 3.3.6. I have followed the example in https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/bootstrap-modal.html but just couldn't get the icon in first column to appear.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/vendor/datatables/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/vendor/datatables/responsive.bootstrap.min.css"> 

  </head>

  <body>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger</td>
                <td>Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td>5421</td>
                <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer</td>
                <td>Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
                <td>9239</td>
                <td>j.chang@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida</td>
                <td>Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
                <td>7439</td>
                <td>z.frank@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita</td>
                <td>Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
                <td>4389</td>
                <td>z.serrano@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer</td>
                <td>Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
                <td>3431</td>
                <td>j.acosta@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="asset/js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="asset/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/vendor/jquery.responsiveTabs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/vendor/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/vendor/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/vendor/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/js/vendor/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>   

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: {
            details: {
                display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal( {
                    header: function ( row ) {
                        var data = row.data();
                        return 'Details for '+data[0]+' '+data[1];
                    }
                } ),
                renderer: function ( api, rowIdx, columns ) {
                    var data = $.map( columns, function ( col, i ) {
                        return '<tr>'+
                                '<td>'+col.title+':'+'</td> '+
                                '<td>'+col.data+'</td>'+
                            '</tr>';
                    } ).join('');

                    return $('<table class="table"/>').append( data );
                }
            }
        }
    } );
} );

</scirpt>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

change the reference

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/vendor/datatables/responsive.bootstrap.min.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.2/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css">
```

as your local reference for responsive bootstrap is not working
please check the relative path
and even if its not working then

add a class with style

```
.yourclass{
top: 8px;
left: 4px;
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
color: white;
border: 2px solid white;
border-radius: 16px;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px #444;
box-sizing: content-box;
text-align: left;
font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
text-indent: 4px;
line-height: 16px;
content: '+';
background-color: #337ab7;
}
```

and use it in you first column

Comment: doesn't work. I added to first column like <td class="yourclass">Tiger</td> but it jut appear a blue circle in the thead section and nothing work at all

Comment: please refer to <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.2/css/responsive/2.0.2/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css">.I think the local library is not working or is not compatible.Use the cdn version.I have just provided you the css style for the button that I got from developer tool.

Comment: I downloaded from CDN and it' exactly the same file